# Crystal C bindings: argument const unsigned char **

Tags: crystal-lang

This is a signature of a C function that I'm trying to use (which produces an array of binary data):

```
long get_output( const unsigned char ** );
```

And I map it with:

```
fun output = get_output( UInt8** ): Int32
```

In C a working example to use it do:

```
const unsigned char * data;
get_output( &data );
```

But in Crystal:

```
data = uninitialized UInt8
MyLib.output( pointerof( pointerof( data ) ) ) # ERR: pointerof of pointerof not allowed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
data = uninitialized UInt8*
MyLib.output(pointerof(data))
```

Note that the argument you have is `UInt8**` so you need to declare a variable of type `UInt8*`.

However, Crystal supports this idiom really nicely, with the `out` keyword: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/c_bindings/out.html

```
MyLib.output(out data)
# use data
```

This last way is preferred because it's more DRY, you don't have to repeat the type.

Also be careful, long usually maps to Int64. In general there are good aliases under `LibC`, for example `LibC::Char`, `LibC::Long`, etc.